# Unable to run snapcraft :Additional properties are not allowed

Tags: 16.04, c++, ubuntu-core, snap

While running snapcraft,i was getting following error,
Issues while validating `snapcraft.yaml`:

> Additional properties are not allowed ('source' was unexpected)

I am trying to run c++ code from my local directory,on snapcraft
my `snapcraft.yaml` is

```
 name: calculator-v1-example

version: 0.1

summary: arithmetic operation 

description: perform simple arithmetic operation getting input from the user

grade: stable 

confinement: strict 

build-packages: [gcc, g++]

parts:

  example:

    plugin: cmake

source: .src

apps:

  example:

    command: bin/example
```

please someone give directions.

Answer (score 1):

`source` needs to be at the same level of `plugin` as it is a property of the `example` part.