# Snapcraft does not allow additional property 'binaries'

Tags: snap, dotnet

When I run snapcraft with this file :

```
name: hwapp-sample
version: 1.0
summary: sample app
description: sample app

binaries:
   hellodnx:
       exec: hwapp/hwapp.dll

parts:
   dnxsample:
       plugin: dump
       source: hwapp
       stage-packages:
       - libunwind8
```

I get this error :

> Issues while validating snapcraft.yaml: Additional properties are not
>   allowed ('binaries' was unexpected)

I have seen the `binaries` keyword being used on the internet [here](http://hypernephelist.com/2015/10/07/run-net-core-app-on-ubuntu-snappy.html) and [here](https://gist.github.com/LefterisJP/f58943095539630b4ad2). [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852559/unable-to-run-snapcraft-additional-properties-are-not-allowed) question does not have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guides you link to are very old. The format & syntax of snapcraft.yaml has changed quite a bit since then. I would recommend using the official documentation which is located at https://snapcraft.io/docs/

For your specific issue, the format is as below:-

```
apps:
   hellodnx:
       command: hwapp/hwapp.dll
```

This is fully documented here:- https://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/metadata

Comment: The error went away. I now get the following error when I run hwapp-sample.hellodnx : "exec: /snap/hwapp-sample/x1/hwapp.dll: not found". Any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a link to the project : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l13vcqr1dk0ix0i/AAA8MwXPTHY9cy94Z1P2DZrWa?dl=0

Comment: Two issues here. One, the permissions on the binary files in ./hwapp are too restrictive, no execute permission for people other than the owner (which in snapd will be root).
```-rwxr--r-- 2 alan alan 4608 Feb 22 18:56 hwapp.dll```

Comment: Second issue, you're not bundling the necessary mono runtime needed by hwapp.dll, which you will need to do in the stage-packages section of your yaml.